# Amore, more, ore, re переклад українською та чи є латинсько-український словник?

Tags: переклад, resource-request, українські-словники, from-latin

Трапився на очі сьогодні латинський крилатий вислів **Amicus amore, more, ore, re cognoscitur**.

Окрім цікавого мовного прийому - логогрифу **`amore, more, ore, re`** (*що наштовхнуло на окреме запитання*) звернула увагу на існування різних варіантів перекладу цього афоризму:

***Друг пізнається з любові, звичок, мови та справ*** -
 дослідження [Прийоми мовної гри з фонетичним образом слова в латинській мові](http://www.medievist.org.ua/2015/09/blog-post_28.html) Н. Корольової, КНУ

***Приятель пізнається завдяки любові, звичаям (характеру), мові, вчинкам*** -
 [Світлична Є.І., Толок І.О. Латинська мова. Підручник. - К.: Центр учбової літератури, 2011. - 440 с.](http://mgu.edu.ua/docs/biblioteka/Latynska_mova.pdf)

***Любов, характер, слова, дії*** (*amore, more, ore, re*) - [Список латинських висловів, Вікіпедія](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA_%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%96%D0%B2)

Хотілося б дізнатися, чи існує якийсь латинсько-український словник, щоб можна було звірити наявні варіанти перекладу?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Хоча це питання не зовсім про українську мову, та я відповім. Нормальних латинсько-українських словників онлайн немає взагалі, з відсканованих паперових найкращий це [словник Скорини](http://toloka.to/t77265), та як на мене він слабкенький. Я трохи знаю латину, але достатньо, аби пояснити цей вислів з точки зору граматики та лексики, то ж давайте я сам вам все поясню. Взагалі, словником латини непросто користуватися, бо по слову з тексту не завжди легко віднайти його словникову форму.

По-перше, це речення в пасивному стані, граматичний підмет (але фактичний пацієнс, об’єкт дії) тут *amicus* «друг», іменник в називному відмінку. Присудок тут *cognoscitur* «пізнається, є таким, якого пізнають», дієслово 3-ї особи однини теперішнього часу пасивного стану. Все, що між цими двома словами, тобто саме *amore, more, ore, re*, – це перелік інструментів, засобів, якими або за допомогою яких виконується дія, оте пізнання. Взагалі, за своєю структурою це речення аналоґічне українському «Цвях молотком забиваться», тут у нас назва інструменту, «молоток», стоїть в орудному відмінку, в який назви інструментів завжди й ставляться в подібних реченнях. В латині ж орудного відмінку як такого немає, нашому орудному відповідає латинський [відкладний відмінок](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2), аблятив, на що вказують закінчення **-е** у всіх чотирьох слів. Розбіжності в українських перекладах обумовлені саме характером латинського відкладного відмінку, у формі якого злилися три праідноевропейські відмінки: орудний, місцевий та відкладний. Чистий відкладний відмінок відповідає на питання «Від кого? Від чого?», тобто є, так би мовити, «анти-давальним», саме тому ті чотири слова можна перекласти як «**з** любові, звичок, мови та справ». Можна було б перекласти й просто орудним, «любов’ю, звичками, мовою та справами», але українською говорити «пізнавати чимось» незвично, тут проситься якийсь прийменник для позначення знаряддя, наприклад «**за допомогою** любові, звичок, мови та справ», або як у вашому другому варіянті «**завдяки** любові, звичаям (характеру), мові, вчинкам». По синтаксису це все.

Щодо морфології, то всі ті чотири слова в цьому реченні стоять *в однині*, тому переклад «звички/звичаї», «слова» та «справи/вчинки/дії» дещо відсувають нас від ориґіналу, та це зумовлене тим, що українською воно так природніше, в однині воно звучало б дивно: «Друг пізнається з любові, звички, слова та справи». Ваш третій переклад, де лише ці чотири слова та ще й у називному відмінку — це просто цитата, й зрозуміла вона буде лише тим, хто знає повний вислів, на кшталт того, як у нас кажуть «Горбатого...», а далі можна й не казати, бо всім і так зрозуміло.

Щодо значення слів. [*Amor, amōris*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/amor#Noun_8) тут найпростіше, бо це просто «любов» чи «статевий потяг». Далі складніше, три подальших слова є винятково багатозначними й концептуальними.

- [mōs, mōris](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/mos#Noun_7) — це воля, норовливість, звичка, мораль, якість, закон. Об’єднує все це «звичка, мораль, моральність вчинків», це слово ще відоме з вислову «O tempora, o mores!» — «О часи, о звичаї!» Від цього слова походять слова «мораль» та «моральний»
- [ōs, ōris](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/os#Noun_13) — головне значення «рот», саме від цього слова походить слово «оральний», інші значення є похідними від основного: «обличчя», «вираз обличчя», «вигляд», та поетичне «мовлення, вимова, красномовство».
- [rēs, reī](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/res#Noun_5) — це те саме *res*, що у слові *res publica* «республіка», яке українською зкалькували через польську як «річ посполита», в моєму словнику стаття цього слова займає майже сторінку, лише основних значень у нього десь 12: «річ, предмет, істота», «справа, випадок», «битва, подвиг», «дійсність», «майно», «зиск, вигода», «засада, підґрунтя» — все це об’єднується поняттям «предмет, дія», та хоча ці два слова здаються антонімами, у їхньому поєднанні нічого дивного немає, бо кожний предмет, наприклад камінюка, насправді теж є процесом. Це слово в аблятиві множини буде *rebus* «від речей», з цієї форми походить наше слово «ребус» — крутиголовка, в якій слово розгадують, відштовхуючися від назв намальованих речей.

Як ви бачите, семантичні поля в цих слів такі, що годі й підібрати українські слова, чиї поля б співпадали з їхніми, тож кожному перекладачеві доводиться йти на поступки й обирати такі українські слова, семантичні поля яких лише частково перекривають значення отих латинських слів, тому й маємо різні переклади.